# how to create a recordset for use in bulk insert?

Tags: node.js, sql-server

I am trying to bulk insert JSON data into SQL Server with nodejs using `mssql`. When I pull data from SQL to generate a recordset it works, but when I copy the format and try to write JSON like a recordset it fails. How can I correctly insert JSON into SQL using bulk (assuming all columns as max length strings)?

Based on the nodejs `mssql` package documentation [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql#bulk-table-options-callback):

> TIP: You can also create Table variable from any recordset with recordset.toTable(). You can optionally specify table type name in the first argument.

```
let rec=await pool.request().query(`select top(2) * from YBPC`) //<<<<WORKS
//let rec={recordset:[{a:'a'},{a:'b'}]}  //<<<<<<FAILS

const table=rec.recordset.toTable('testtable')
table.create = true  

try{
    const request = new sql.Request(pool)
    let res=await request.bulk(table)
    console.log(`SUCCESS:`,res)
}catch(e){
    console.error(`ERR:`,e)
}
return
```

I could just create a table using my code below but my question is specifically about the recordset object

```
//parse JSON to add to table object
let colnames=Object.keys(rec[0])
colnames.map(k=>table.columns.add(k, sql.NVarChar(sql.MAX), { nullable: true/*, primary: true*/ }));    
rec.forEach(row => table.rows.add.apply(table.rows,Object.values(row)));
```